# Android get Session Initiation protocol(SIP) calling states

Tags: android, sip

Can anyone provide me with an example for catching outgoing call states for a SIP call?

Here is the link for doing that using TelephonyManager [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html).

But I want something similar for sip calls.

Comment: are you using Default Sip?(included from android 2.3)

Comment: I am using Sipdroid and device is Samsung Galaxy plus 7, Android version 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a packet capture (root access) from your device and look at the SIP messages, understanding of SIP call flow will give you call state from SIP message you are looking at.